# Hiding a UIViews backface visibility, when rotating around in 3D space - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, catransform3drotate

In CSS3 there is a property called `backface-visibility` ([Mozilla Developer Network's description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/backface-visibility))

Is there something similar in Cocoa Touch/ Objective C, which allows me to hide the contents of a UIView (apart from it's background colour) when rotating it in 3D space?

(There is also a HTML5 demo of what I mean here: [CSS3 demo](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/))

I really don't want to have to hard code in animations to hide/fade out/in the subviews!!

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the `doubleSided` property of the view's layer to `NO`.  The default value is `YES`.

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea about this property. Sadly though, my UIView's background colour (UIImage pattern) also disappears.